# Is it possible to automatically input value to the terminal when using an ssh connection?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have the username, ip addresses and passwords for specific servers. I want to connect to these servers using sshpass with ssh connection. It would be my first connection to these servers, so ssh will save their fingerprints. I need to write code that would handle any prompt asking me if I want to continue connecting and for the password.

The problem is that since its a new connection, it will prompt if I want to continue and I don't want to type "yes" for every server. I will be dealing with over 50 servers at one point and I don't want to manually type "yes" and then the password.

This is a (dummy) code of what I actually have in bash:

```
ip="192.168.111.111"
user="user"
password="password"

sshpass -p $password $user@$ip "exit"
```

I get an error of `Host key verification failed` for this code.

So then I tried: `$user@$ip "exit"` and I get a prompt asking me is I want to continue connecting (yes/no). I don't want to type "yes" each time and then the password for each server. Can have some code that can manually do this for you?

Thanks. Let me know if further explanation is required. Also, I want to avoid using the Expect tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable host key checking by adding this option to ~/.ssh/config under the relevant hostnames

```
Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

You can use wildcards to match ranges of IPs (for example `Host *` could be used for a global setting). With this option in your config, you should be able to use this command:

```
sshpass -p"$password" ssh "$user"@"$ip"
```

If you prefer not to edit the config file, you can specify the option on the command line instead:

```
sshpass -p"$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$user"@"$ip"
```

Note that normally, it is recommended to use SSH keys rather than passwords to authenticate in this kind of scenario, as this facilitates automatic processes that would otherwise require a prompt. It also can be more secure, as it means that your password isn't stored in plaintext somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!. I keep getting `Bad port 'password'` for the second option you gave. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I will up vote and accept if this answer actually works for me

Comment: @Alias I have edited my answer, hopefully adding the option to your configuration file works. Otherwise, you might want to take a look at using SSH keys. [This answer on serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password) is relevant.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for your effort. +1. But its not what I am looking for

Comment: @Alias I have updated the commands in the answer. Hopefully they should work now. Let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: @TomFenech I'm getting an error (but its not specified). It's displaying the usage of ssh with all of its options. So its not connecting to the servers

Comment: @Alias If you do `set -x` before you run the command, it will show you exactly what is being run.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks a lot! It was an error on my part.